# Problemas con AVD en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, avd

necesito una pequeña ayuda, el emulador de android studio me esta presentando un particular error, al momento de lanzar un `avd nexus_5` con `API 21`, aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego el emulador se inicia pero en pantalla negra... que podría ser?

Comment: Nunca he sido partidario de usar los emuladores proveídos por Android Studio.
Te recomiendo utilizar [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com), tiene mucho mejor rendimiento que el emulador, puedes instalar gapps y luego aplicaciones desde la tienda ya que corre sobre maquinas virtuales. Saludos.

Comment: A veces es solo cuestión de esperar lo suficiente, no veo en tu imagen algún error.

Comment: @SandyAtencio como comenta Joel, trata de agregar más información desplegada en la consola, al menos para mi eso no me parece un mensaje que pueda determinar el problema.

Comment: Podria poner que OS esta usando, asi como su procesador quizas ayude en su pregunta, pero comentario usted podria mirar si tiene suficiente RAM para lanzar el emulador ect, tambien podria provar a habilitar o desabilitar "Use Host GPU" en su emulador. Cuando dice que la pantalla esta en negra, a que se refiere, es totalmente negra o puede ver los botones y demas del emulador me refiero a si puede ver el Skin del emulador. Saludos

Comment: Tenaz, definitivamente nada como los emuladores de Android en Visual Studio 2015, los de Google si están muchos , pero muchos años atrás en tecnología...

Comment: @ClarkXP desafortunadamente no puedo utilizar genymotion debido a que  mi tarjeta de vídeo no es compatible con OpenGL 2.0 y me pide actualizar los drivers pero ya todos estan actualizados

Comment: @JoelIbaceta he esperado incluso casi media hora pero el emulador aun sigue como se ve en la imagen que les muestro donde formulo la pregunta

Comment: @AngelAngel el SO que uso es Ubuntu 14.04, procesador Intel Core 2 Duo, 4 de RAM y al momento de configurar el emulador desabilito la opcion de "Use Host GPU" y la pantalla sale totalmente en negra como se muestra en la imagen que se visualiza donde formulo la pregunta

Comment: @SandyAtencio probaste habilitando la opcion de Host GPU? se de mucha gente que tuvo problemas por eso.

Comment: @jirungaray si habilito esa opcion, peor no se ejeucta nada!!

Comment: Podrias checar si las imagenes de android estan correctamente descargadas

Comment: A mi me ha ocurrido a veces a cause de falta de memoria (o parecido: configuraste resolución muy alta de pantalla). ¿Cuánta memoria tiene la PC? ¿Cuánta se ha asignado al emulador? Revisa si en el log del emulador hay algun mensaje relevante. Prueba iniciando el emulador con el argumento `-debug-all` Busca mensajes relacionados con SurfaceFlinger, gralloc, etc. (p.ej. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24270797/599926 )

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar **Genymotion**, más funciones, menos errores, más fluidez y más opciones de configuración para cada dispositivo, mas detalles [aquí](https://www.genymotion.com/download/).

Answer (score 3):

Creo que su error viene por aquí

> emulator window was out of view and was recentered (aunque ha sido recentrado)

Usted puede tratar lo siguiente:

Diríjase al directorio donde se encuentra creado su virtual device, la ruta puede ser algo así `/suUsuario/.android/avd/Nexus_S_API_21.avd`. Si usted no puede ver el directorio `.android` asegurese de que puede ver los ficheros ocultos <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>. Una vez dentro, abra el fichero con el nombre: `emulator-user.ini` y modifique las líneas:

- window.x
- window.y

para que queden de la siguiente manera:

- window.x = 0
- window.y = 0

Notas para Windows: puede ser algo así C:\Users\tuUsuario

Si de la manera anterior no le funciona, puede tratar con lo siguente:
Selecione la ventana donde se muestra el emulador, a continuación pulse <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> despues la tecla <kbd>M</kbd> ahora puede mover con las flechas del teclado o bien con el ratón.

---

Movido de mi comentario:

> Usted podria mirar si tiene suficiente RAM para lanzar el emulador
>   ect, tambien podria probar a habilitar o desabilitar "Use Host GPU" en
>   su emulador.

---

Puede tratar con el siguiente comando, igual obtiene alguna salida que le aclare algo, por ejemplo si se queda sin espacio para ejecutar el emulador ect. Por otro lado trate de crear una imagen del dispositivo lo mas simple que pueda para descartar falta de recursos en el host (y probar diferentes system imagen).

```
/home/code/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none -debug-init -logcat '*:v'
```

---

También puede tratar de usar [AS 2.0 preview](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0-preview) me lo comentó [Webserveis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2230/webserveis) pues bajo mi punto de vista la emulacion sin el uso de KVM, ha mejorado con respecto a otras versiones, igual le ayuda en su problema.

Comment: aunque igual no tiene bateria

Answer (score 0):

Alguna vez tuve un error parecido a este, lo solucione instalando la herramienta INTEL HAXM es un motor de visualización de hardware que ayuda mas que nada a aumentar la velocidad de el emulador de Android.

Afortunadamente existe la versión para Linux.

[Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator)